# Entry cell loses focus on button press in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have buttons that act like a keyboard when pressed on it must fill an entry field that is focused. but it doesn't work, because the button press causes the entry to lose focus. 
can anyone give me a hint to solve this problem?

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   Button button = (Button)sender;
        string pressed = button.Text;
        if (this.FirstDigit.IsFocused)
        {
            this.FirstDigit.Text += pressed;
        }and so on ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it is hard to keep the entry's focus when a button is clicked.

I write a **WorkAroud** for you, when the entry is `Unfocused`, use a `previousEntry` to record this entry:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public Entry previousEntry;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        first.Unfocused += (object sender, FocusEventArgs e) => {
            previousEntry = (Entry)sender;
        };

        second.Unfocused += (object sender, FocusEventArgs e) => {
            previousEntry = (Entry)sender;
        };

        third.Unfocused += (object sender, FocusEventArgs e) => {
            previousEntry = (Entry)sender;
        };
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button button = (Button)sender;
        string pressed = button.Text;

        if (previousEntry != null)
        {
            previousEntry.Text += pressed;
        }

    }    
}
```

And in **Xaml**:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->

    <Button Text="click me" Clicked="Button_Clicked"  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

    <Entry x:Name="first" Text="1+" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    <Entry x:Name="second" Text="2+" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    <Entry x:Name="third" Text="3+" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

</StackLayout>
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would call

```
entry.Focus();
```

in that method to make it work.

Comment: It works until a button is pressed,
by clicking a button the entry focus is removed and I couldn't determine which entry should be filled.